# HTML5 Canvas Context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I have started reading/experimenting with HTML5.  All the tutorials I've seen for the HTML5 Canvas follow the pattern of JavaScript getting the canvas by ID, getting a 2d context, and then working with the context:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
 <script>
   var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.fillStyle="cyan";
   ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,75);
 </script>
```

I was wondering if there is any enumeration or constants for getting a Context for the Canvas.

Something like `Context.2D`, `Context.3D`, etc. (I know this isn't a real constant, just wondering if there is something like it somewhere in JavaScript or HTML5).

Every example I've seen, the call that is made is simply `getContext("2d")`.  This seems brittle, and also doesn't tell me what other (if any) contexts might be available.

Comment: I think it's just `2d` or `webgl` for now.

Comment: @paul thanks for informing me about webgl ... I didn't know that was one of the strings that could be passed.  I assumed it would be '3d'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call `getContext` only once, and if you call it again it will return null if the canvas has already been initialized with a different context type. If you call it again with the same context type, it will return the same context. Null is also returned if a canvas does not support a given context ID string.

In other words, each canvas has only one context.

> doesn't tell me what other (if any) contexts might be available.

For this there is the method `supportsContext(someContextString)`, which is very new to the spec (March 2012) that has yet to be implemented in any browser.

There's additionally `setContext` that is not yet supported in any browser (might be in a few nightlies). Note that `setContext` is only useful if you've made a headless context, because a canvas that already has a context (via use of getContext) will throw an error if you try to set a different one.

Anyway, the reason that the argument is a string is to allow for browser-specific extensions to the canvas. After all, MS might want to implement `getContext('2d-directx')` (they probably would never actually do this).

The only strings you'll see these days are `"2d"`, `"webgl"`, and `"webgl-experimental"`.

Comment: That is a tremendously informative answer, thank you for sharing all that great information. I had never heard of `supportsContext` method or the not-yet-supported setContext.